# Datatable won't update my DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, datarow, tableadapter

```
usersTableAdapter usersTA = new usersTableAdapter();
var usersTable = new users.usersDataTable();
usersTA.Fill(usersTable);

VK_BDayParser.users.usersRow row = usersTable.FindByid(currentItem.id);
row.BeginEdit();
row.last_name = "********";
row.EndEdit();

row.AcceptChanges();
usersTable.AcceptChanges();

int result = usersTA.Update(usersTable);
```

SQL server 2012.

I used generated classes from VS 2013 to database

I try to update row in my DB, in 'usersRow row' this changes works, but in DB has no changes. What am I doing wrong? `result` is always 0.

Comment: Remove the AcceptChanges calls. Both

Comment: Also check your connection string. Are you using `user instance` and/or `AttachDbFileName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding on what the [AcceptChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) method does.
I think the problem arises from the initial comment in the documentation of the `AcceptChanges` method .

> Commits all the changes made to this table since the last time
>   AcceptChanges was called.

Many people think that this means 'commits to the database table', instead it means 'commits to the in-memory instance of the datatable object'.

Then, the following comment on the docs, hints to what is really happening there.

> When AcceptChanges is called, any DataRow object still in edit mode
>   successfully ends its edits. The DataRowState also changes: all Added
>   and Modified rows become Unchanged, and Deleted rows are removed.

So, there is this [DataRow.RowState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate(v=vs.110).aspx) property that express what is the current state of the in-memory rows belonging to the in-memory instance of the DataTable. And it is this state that helps the `DataAdapter.Update` method in discovering what to do with the rows.

In other words the Update method decides to update the database table only for the  rows that are not [`RowState==DataRowState.Unchanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate(v=vs.110).aspx). But calling AcceptChanges 'commits' these rows and their state becomes Unchanged. No update then.